# distribution function, calculating $f(y)$ and $F(Y)$

Tags: probability

The length of time to failure (in hundreds of hours) for a transistor is a random variable $Y$ with distribution function given by:

$F(y) = 0$ when $y <0$, and $1-e^{-y^2}$ when y greater than or equal to $0$

a.) Show that $F(y)$ has the properties of a distribution function.

$F(-\infty) = 0$

$F(\infty) = 1$

$F(Y_2) - F(Y_1) \ge 0$

b.) find $f(y)$

I just took the derivative of $1-e^{-y^2}$ which is $2e^{-y^2}$

c.) Find the probability that the transistor operates for at least $200$ hours, find $P(Y \ge 2)$ for y in $100$s of hours

$P(Y \ge 2) = 1 - F(1) = 1 -  1-e^{-1^2}$

d.) Find $P(Y > 100 | Y \le 200)$

$P(Y > 100 \cap Y \le 200) / P(Y \le 200) = ?/F(2)$

Are these correct? I am not $100$% sure how to do $P(Y > 100 \cap Y \le 200)$ for part d.

Comment: (a) You're not showing how you proved monotonicity, and you don't seem to have checked right-continuity (c) Why $F(1)$? (d) Idea is sound, but you need to finish it...

Comment: Hint for (c) and (d): $P(a < X \leq b) = F(b) - F(a)$.

Comment: @fgp how would I do that? Would that be taking the limit? For c, because it it is looking for everything that is greater than or equal to 2, can't you just do 1 - all that is 1, which will give you everything else that is 2 or greater? For d, I don't know how to change the P(Y > 100 and Y <= 200) to some F.

Comment: For the numerator (d), you want $\Pr(1\lt Y\le 2)$. This is $\Pr(Y\le 2)-\Pr(Y\le 1)$, which is $(1-e^{-4})-(1-e^{-1})$, which is $e^{-1}-e^{-4}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. Would part c just be F(2)? I am confused about part c. Or would it be 1 - F(2)?

Comment: First a comment. For a continuous distribution such as ours, $\Pr(Y=a)=0$ for all $a$. So $\Pr(Y\ge a)=\Pr(Y\gt a)$. Informally, for continuous distributions, we don't need to be careful about distinguishing between $\ge$ and $\gt$. (For discrete distributions, we do have to be careful.) For c), $\Pr(Y\ge 2)=1-\Pr(Y\lt 2)=1-(1-e^{-4})=e^{-4}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas ahhh I see. I did not know that. Thank you so much!I am a little confused about how to prove a, do you have any helpful hints for that?

Comment: I do not know the level of the course. Maybe the only properties you were given are the ones you listed. (If so, the list was incomplete.) To show that $F(y)$ is non-decreasing, you want to show that if $a\lt b$ then $F(a)\le F(b)$. This is obvious if $a\le 0$, so assume $0\lt a\lt b$. We want to show that $1-e^{-a^2}\lt 1-e^{-b^2}$, or equivalently that $e^{-b^2}\lt e^{-a^2}$. This is clear, for $x\gt 0$ the function $e^{-x^2}$ is decreasing. (More)

Comment: @AndréNicolas alright awesome! Thank you for all the help!

Comment: If your course was a careful one, there is a further condition, $\lim_{y\to a^+} F(y)=F(a)$. (As we approach $a$ **from the right** the cdf approaches $F(a)$.) This is clear in this case, the cdf is actually everywhere continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so your CDF is $$
  F(y) = \begin{cases}
    1 - e^{-y^2} &\text{for $y \geq 0$} \\
    0 &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$

**A.** Show that $F$ is a distribution function

Showing that $\lim_{y\to-\infty} F(y) = 0$ and $\lim_{y\to+\infty} F(y) = 1$ and that $F$ is monotone is a good start. You also need that $F$ is right-continuous, i.e. that for all $y$ you have $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0,\epsilon > 0} F(y+\epsilon) = F(y)$. In your case, $F$ is even continuous - as the combination of continuous functions - except possibly at $0$, since that's where you switch from one case to another. But since $1 - e^{-0^2} = 0$, $F$ is continuous at $0$ also.

**B.** The idea is sound, but your result is wrong. Check how you compute that derivative...

**C.** In general, you have $P(Y \geq y) = P(Y = y) + P(Y > y) = P(Y = y) + 1 - P(Y \leq y)$. Now, $P(Y = y) = F(y) - \lim_{\epsilon\to 0, \epsilon > 0} F(y-\epsilon)$. Since your distribution function is not only right-continuous, but fully *continuous*, that limit is always $0$, and you get $$
  P(Y \geq y) = 1 - P(Y \leq y) = 1 - F(y) \text{.}
$$

**D.** As André and I already pointed out in the comment, $$
  P(a < X \leq b) = F(b) - F(a) \text{.}
$$
Note that, just as in (c), you may exchange $<$ with $\leq$, and also $>$ with $\geq$ *if* the distribution function is *fully* continuous, i.e. also left-continuous and not only  right-continuous as all distribution functions must be. Your distribution function satisfies that property, but of course not all distribution functions do.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user125627 BTW, non-continuous distribution functions are *exactly* those which assign non-zero probability to singleton events such as $P(Y = y)$. I suggest you try working out the distribution function for a simple probability distribution over $3$ possible outcomes.

Comment: okay. Wow a lot of information haha. Will do! thanks.

Comment: Very nice thorough answer!